# Why is [:] needed in python array when manipulating it? (rotation problem)

Tags: python, arrays, slice

Why is the [:] needed in the array. I understand that slicing using [:] creates a copy but why is the copy needed here? Also I tried creating copy with a temp variable which didn't work. This is for array rotation problem.

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
      k=k%len(nums)
      g = len(nums) -k
      nums[:] = nums[g:] + nums[:g]

A=Solution()
MyList=[1,2,3,4]

A.rotate(MyList,2)
assert (MyList == [3, 4, 1, 2])
```

Comment: it changes the array in place as opposed to overwiting the pointer to the array

Comment: This is more about numpy than python.

Comment: ok, why is overwriting the pointer to the array problematic here?

Comment: Related: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

After the assignment to `MyList`, the list `[1,2,3,4]` is created and MyList contains a reference to it.

When you call the function `rotate()` with `MyList` passed in as the `nums` argument, nums contains a reference to the same list `[1,2,3,4]` that `MyList` refers to.

If you want to modify that list within the `rotate()` function, you can do something like `nums[0] = 99` or `nums[1:2] = [33,66]` or `nums[:] = nums[g:] + nums[:g]` and these will act on the same list that was created in the original assignment to `MyList`.

The examples above that use slice notation `[:]` for the mutable sequence `nums` on the left-hand side in an assignment statement (with `=`) can be understood according to the Python docs on [Mutable sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
Operation       Result
---------       ------
s[i:j] = t      slice of s from i to j is replaced by the contents of the iterable t
```

If instead you were to write `nums = nums[g:] + nums[:g]` inside the `rotate()` function, this would simply update `nums` to now be a reference to a brand new list (the result of the `+` operation on `nums[g:]` and `nums[:g]`) which is completely different from the object that `MyList` refers to.

And this is the reason that the `[:]` syntax is needed on the left-hand side of the assignment to `nums[:]`.

Comment: @KInformationist Do you need any more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because, inside of the function definition, 'nums' is a local variable that references whatever object was passed in as a function argument. Reassigning that variable does not change the object passed in, only the reference.

What the code:

```
templist = nums[g:] + nums[:g]
nums = templist
```

does is assign the local variable 'nums', inside of rotate, to point towards the templist object. The object passed in is unchanged.

In the case of the working code, [:] is NOT creating a copy of the list. Instead it is slice notation, telling the 'num' object to loop through its values and assign them to the values gives on the right of the = sign. It is mostly equivalent to:

```
templist = nums[g:] + nums[:g]
for i in range(len(templist)):
    nums[i] = templist[i]
```

Comment: I find the part of this answer that references the working code confusing (and probably wrong) as currently written. It says "telling the 'num' object to loop through its values and assign them to the values given on the right of the = sign". The working code reads `nums[:] = nums[g:] + nums[:g]`, and the `[:]` causes the slice of the object 'num' (a list, which is an immutable sequence) on the *left* of the = sign to be replaced by the contents of the iterable on the right of the = sign. Docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Comment: Correction: "... the object 'nums' (a list, which is a *mutable sequence*) on the left of the = sign ..."

Comment: That said, the core observation in your first paragraph regarding reassignment not changing the object passed in to the function is on target.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the answer is: you don't!
nums[:] = ... means that you are assigning everything in nums to something. Line five is the same as

```
    nums = nums[g:] + nums[:g]
```

don't forget to write

```
    return nums
```

at the end of the function to return nums.

Comment: This is simply not true. You need only run the OP's code with both to see this.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked.

Comment: also, what is OP?

Comment: OP == original post. When you take the code (all the code) in the question, change `nums[:] = ` to `num =` you will get an `AssertionError`.